# Disabling default namespaces

Tags: namespaces, rust

Rust seems to `use` some namespaces by default. For example, I don't have to use `std::string::String` and can simply type `String`. How can I define my own `struct String` without clashing with `std::string::String`? And where can I find a list of the namespaces that are included by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own `String` by... creating your own String:

```
struct String {
    len: u8,
}

fn main() {}
```

You can then disambiguate which `String` you want using fully-qualified paths:

```
fn main() {
    // String::new();
    // error: type `String` does not implement any method in scope named `new`

    std::string::String::new();
}
```

The full list of automatically-imported items can be found [in the prelude](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/c78c0994b1df5e365058f301330d06fa035c3734/src/libstd/prelude/v1.rs) (version 1, at the time of writing).

Answer (score 7):

It's not a matter of 'default namespaces', it's [the prelude](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/index.html).